# Restrict deleting all selected checkbox if it is last record

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have list of line items dynamically populating from database. 
I want to restrict deletion if single line item exists.

Now it is getting deleted without checking.

Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form#form1").submit (function() {
           if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
                return true;
            } 
            else {
                alert("Please select at least one item !");
                return false;
            }           
        });

    });
</script>
```

my form

```
<form class="form" id="form1" action="" method="post">

</form>
```

and the checkbox is

```
<input class='check_all' checked="checked" type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/>
```

I tried getting length like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) = 1 
{
alert("Can't delete!");
                return false;
}
```

But it did't check.

Where i am doing wrong i am not getting

Comment: when you click the checkbox a line item is deleted ?

Comment: yes line items gets deleted.even if it is one. Actually this jquery i am using only for message display.  for delete i have code like this `<td><a onClick="javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');" href="delete_quote_item.php?id=<?php echo $row1['id']?>&& QuoteID=<?php echo $QuoteID; ?>" data-toggle='confirmation' data-placement='top'>X</a></td>`

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you add a fiddle ?